# c - char array only prints first char

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char

This is just a part of the code and it is simplified for this question.
I would like to be able to store the word into my struct, the whole word not just the first char.

```
struct lexics{
    enum token token;
    char lexeme[LEXEME_MAX];
};

int main(void) {
  char a[]="";
  
  a[0]='w';
  a[1]='h';
  a[2]='i';
  a[3]='l';
  a[4]='e';
  
          
  struct lexics rs={WHILE_KEYWORD,*a};
  printf("%s\n",rs.lexeme);
}
```

---

this only prints w and I need it to print while

1. I cannot use anything other than the  `char a[]="";`
2. a must be build in this way

When I print result it is while but when I put inside the struct it is only w

Comment: You are writing outside of the bounds of the array in `result[1]='h';` (the type of `result` is `char[1]`) fix it using `char result[6] = "";`

Comment: How is `result` involved? What does "must be build this way" mean? Manually assigning characters without terminating 0 byte?  It is not a valid string, you know? And it is not used at all, anyway.

Comment: This question needs clarifications, because a declaration like `char result[] = ""` is very rarely a sensible declaration, and you're not even using it. Plus, what is `WHILE_KEYWORD` and `LEXEME_MAX`? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: There was a typo from testing different stuff...it is fixed and the problem is solved...Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `struct lexics rs = {WHILE_KEYWORD, *a};`, you are effectively putting the first element of `a` inside of the `lexics.lexeme` array. Try using a function that copies the entire array:

```c
struct lexics rs = {WHILE_KEYWORD};
strncpy(rs.lexeme, a, LEXEME_MAX - 1);
rs.lexeme[LEXEME_MAX - 1] = 0; // to be sure that the string is properly terminated :)
```

Comment: Right, I read the documentation for `strncpy` wrong.

Comment: Still unsafe, but 1 character shorter. ;) Should be `strncpy(rs.lexeme, a, LEXEME_MAX); rs.lexeme[LEXEME_MAX - 1]=0;`

Comment: Shouldn't it be safe, since `rs.lexeme` should be initialized to zero?

Comment: OK, in this case you are right. But I would suggest to always use both statements tied together.

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
 char result[]="";
```

does not give you an infinite-length array, it's a one element array (only null-terminator). You need to either have a proper size mentioned, or a long-enough initializer to have a proper size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```c
struct lexics{
    enum token token;
    char lexeme[LEXEME_MAX];
};

...

    struct lexics rs={WHILE_KEYWORD,*a};
    printf("%s\n",rs.lexeme);
```

In C arrays are filled with zero if there are less initializers than elements in the array.

In your code you only provide 1 single `char` to initialize `char lexeme[LEXEME_MAX]` array. This means the array looks like `"w\0\0\0\0..."` and as a result only the first  character is printed.

You must use `strcpy` or `strncpy` to copy the string from array `a` into the array `rs.lexeme`.